# Change Plasma keyboard layout and LO Writer paragraph language with one shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, libreoffice, plasma, macro, desktop-shortcuts

I often write in 2-3 languages in the same text for which I use 3 different keyboard layouts. Thus, I very often have to switch the layouts but also the paragraph language.

I would like to have the paragraph language (and thus the spell checking language) in LO Writer changed when I change the keyboard layout in Plasma. Or the other way around!

Is that even conceivable?

I have a key shortcut associated to a saved macro in LOWriter to change the paragraph language, and a shortcut key to change the kb-layout.

I am curious if the two actions could be somehow, at least theoretically, be made with one keyboard-shortcut.

At the present, if I set the same shortcut for a kb layout and for a LO paragraph language, the first works but the second is disabled (until the first is changed to something different).